# how to design a column to add manually valid time period in django model

Tags: python, django

i have a model namely `SubscribePlan` here it is

```
class SubscribePlan(models.Model):

    plan = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    validity_period = models.DateTimeField()
    number_of_download = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
```

here i want to add a `validity_period` column in such a way where the `admin` will manually add the validity time.I know that django model provides two different datatypes for `Date`one is `DateField()` and another is `DateTimeField()`

and if i am not wrong ,there is two parameter for `DateTimeField()`,one is `auto_now` and another is `auto_now_add`.

**UPDATE**:

But my concern is,i have to provide such a model for the admin where admin can manually put a **valid time period** assume 24 hours or 48 hours or 1 day or 2 days through the Admin interface or Admin panel.

So in this case what should be the `data type` of the model where valid time period can be input manually? or  if the `datatype` is `DateTimeField` then what should be the parameter? **in mention i am using django 1.5**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the `validity_period` should be Integer Field(or Character Field), because it is not a `Date` but just a number which can be used for checking a time period, like this:

For example, lets make a function which will check the validity of a Subscription.

## for Integer Field

```
import datetime
def check_validity(start_time ,validity_period):
    if datetime.datetime.now() <= start_time + datetime.timedelta(hours=validy_period):
      return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

It can also depend on what kind of control(web element) is being used in admin interface for entering the validity period. If the admin interface has a date-time picker or calendar, which returns a DateTime object, for entering the validity period then in your model the validity_period field can be of type DateTimeField() or DateField(). But if admin is providing input like 1 days or 2 days then it should be of IntegerField or CharField.